# BeautifulSoup - how to get items from website, not containing div, as rest of the items

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape job ads from website : https://www.jobs.bg/front_job_search.php?frompage=0&add_sh=1&categories%5B0%5D=29&location_sid=1&keywords%5B0%5D=python&term=#paging

I want to get all visible data - job title, location, short description such as : Full Stack; DBA, Big Data; Data Science, AI, ML and Embedded; Test, QA and scraping part for this is:

```
result = requests.get("https://www.jobs.bg/front_job_search.php?frompage=0&add_sh=1&categories%5B0%5D=29&location_sid=1&keywords%5B0%5D=python&term=#paging").text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result, "lxml")
jobs = soup.find_all('td', class_ = "offerslistRow")
for job in jobs:
    description = find_all('div', class_="card__subtitle mdc-typography mdc-typography--body2")
```

and it is [0] part to be precise, as there are two type short descriptions with same class name, but this is not the issue.

Some ads don't have short description, but they also don't have the mentioned div part(it is not empty, it doesn't exist at all).

Is there a way to get description for such ads as well as "N/A" for example or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to scrape all job details as the question was a bit unclear. I have made a few other changes to your code as well, and handled all possible cases.

The following code should do the job-

```
import bs4
import requests

result = requests.get("https://www.jobs.bg/front_job_search.php?frompage=0&add_sh=1&categories%5B0%5D=29&location_sid=1&keywords%5B0%5D=python&term=#paging").text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result, "lxml")

# find all jobs
jobs = soup.find_all('td', class_ = "offerslistRow")

# list to store job title
job_title=[]

# list to store job location
job_location=[]

# list to store domain and skills
domain_and_skills=[]

# loop through the jobs
for job in jobs:

    # this check is to remove the other two blocks aligned to the right
    if job.find('a',class_="card__title mdc-typography mdc-typography--headline6 text-overflow") is not None: 
        
        # find and append job name
        job_name=job.find('a',class_="card__title mdc-typography mdc-typography--headline6 text-overflow")
        job_title.append(job_name.text)


        # find and append location and salary description
        location_salary_desc=job.find('span',class_='card__subtitle mdc-typography mdc-typography--body2 top-margin') 
        if location_salary_desc is not None:
            job_location.append(location_salary_desc.text.strip())
        else:
            job_location.append('NA')
        
        # find other two descriptions (Skills and domains)
        description = job.find_all(class_="card__subtitle mdc-typography mdc-typography--body2")

        # if both are empty (len=0)
        if len(description)==0:
            domain_and_skills.append('NA')
        
        # if len=1 (can either be skills or domain details)
        elif len(description)==1:
            
            # to check if domain is present and skills is empty
            if description[0].find('div') is None:
                domain_and_skills.append(description[0].text.strip())            
            
            # domain is empty and skills is present
            else:
                # list to store skills
                skills=[]

                # find all images in skills section and get alt attribute which contains skill name
                images=description[0].find_all('img')

                # if no image and only text is present (for example Shell Scripts is not an image, contains text value)
                if len(images)==0:
                    skills.append(description[0].text.strip())
                
                # both image and text is present
                else:
                    # for each image, append skill name in list
                    for image in images:
                        skills.append(image['alt'])
                    
                    # append text to list if not empty
                    if description[0].text.strip() !='':
                        skills.append(description[0].text.strip())
                
                #convert list to string
                skills_string = ','.join([str(skill) for skill in skills])

                domain_and_skills.append(skills_string)
        
        # both domain and skills are present
        else:
            domain_string=description[0].text.strip()

            # similar procedure as above to print skill names
            skills=[]
            images=description[1].find_all('img')
            if len(images)==0:
                skills.append(description[1].text.strip())
            else:
                for image in images:
                    skills.append(image['alt'])
                if description[1].text.strip() !='':
                    skills.append(description[1].text.strip())

            skills_string = ','.join([str(skill) for skill in skills])

            #combine domain and skills
            domain_string=domain_string+','+skills_string

            domain_and_skills.append(domain_string)

for i in range(0,len(job_title)):
    print(job_title[i])
    print(job_location[i])
    print(domain_and_skills[i])
```

Comment: I actually need to have one list with all domain and skills. Also, it is important length of this list to match with length of available jobs, because I am scraping job title, location,  etc. in separate lists and then I have one 'for' loop to get all of them by incrementing counter, representing the index. So, can you please help me to get list with description - if only domain is available, to have it in the list, if only skills are available, to have them in the list, if both are available to add them as one string element to the list or if none are available to add "N/A". Thank you!

Comment: @StefanTončev I have updated the answer to store the values in list, let me know if this solved your issue!

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. Thank you very very much!

Comment: You're welcome :))